# New files cannot read other computer, sharing folder from windows server

Tags: php, window, sharing, windows-server, file-sharing

i'm create website using PHP then i put in windows server. Website running normally i'm also to sharing folder program to client (LAN) and set permission to **Everyone** can read files.

When user upload files then files save to folder program and can see files in windows server. But when client computer access sharing folder, cannot found/read new files from upload. I'm try create file and copy file in folder, client computer can read this files. Why when upload files from PHP, client cannot read file from upload from website PHP ?

i found different permission, when i'm upload from website. this file only 3 permission no permission "**Everyone**"

[image]

This file from create file or copy file, not upload. there have a 4 permission, have a "**Everyone**" permission.

[image]

i'm already test with this code, with chmod but not result :(

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path_with_file_name);
   chmod($path_with_file_name, 0777);
```

or

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path_with_file_name);
   chmod($path_with_file_name, 0755);
```

How to add permission **Everyone** when upload file using web PHP ?

**Server OS : Windows Server 2019**

**Client OS : Windows 10**

How to solve this problem ?
help me thank's

Comment: Set the permissions for Everyone on the directory and choose this folder, subolders and files and replace on existing or some such settings.

Comment: i'm already set permission project "Everyone"

Comment: FYI chmod has no effect on Windows servers. I agree with AbraCadaver - add Everyone to the containing folder.

Comment: @Typel I'm already set permission "Everyone", but no effect >> https://imgur.com/xIAQM4Z

Comment: In the question it is not clear from your wording whether people are trying to "see" the files over a network share or by using a page in your website or some other means. Can you clarify this part?

Comment: When you add Everyone there is a _Replace all child object permissions entries with inheritable permission entries from this object_  Did you check that?